# Ubuntu two passwords Want to change first password

Tags: login, password

Ok,so With Ubuntu I have two passwords the first one I can't figure out how to change. The first password is the start up "phrase" and its a purple screen with the Ubuntu logo and word along with a box to type the password into. The second password in the password into my actual account and it can be changed by system settings. Prob is I can't figure out how to change first password. Please Help.

Comment: Have you encrypted your home folder?